# installation of zorin os 9 onto lenovo thinkserver ts140 will not pick up wifi

Tags: wifi, zorin

There are no updatable drivers, wlan is not detected and wifi is not detected. I have tried every possible thing I can find or know. what am I missing please help.

```
lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I217-LM [8086:153a] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:30a5]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
```

so I am able to connect through ethernet cable. I have no updates for new drivers.

```
sudo lshw -c network
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection I217-LM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 04
       serial: 6c:0b:84:3d:5e:ff
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=2.3.2-k duplex=full firmware=0.13-4 ip= latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:42 memory:f7c00000-f7c1ffff memory:f7c3d000-f7c3dfff ioport:f080(size=32)
```

Comment: What *we* are missing is: i) the specific things you tried and how they failed; ii) your network hardware; iii) any information we can use to help you diagnose the issue. Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: nmcli nm
RUNNING         STATE           WIFI-HARDWARE   WIFI       WWAN-HARDWARE   WWAN      
running         connected       enabled         enabled    enabled         disabled

Comment: iwlist scan
eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and clarify. Also show us the output of `lspci -vv | grep etw` and `ip link show`.

Comment: this command does nothing        UX:~$ lspci -vv | grep etw
ladytrevo@ladytrevo-70A4000HUX:~$

Comment: ip link show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 6c:0b:84:3d:5e:ff brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

Comment: Sigh. Please add that to your question, not in the comment. But don't _replace_ your question with it, just add it. Use the [formatting tools](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to make it come out correctly.

Comment: I am just learning everything never-mind thanks I don't need someone critiquing me

Answer (score 0):

You can't connect to wifi because you don't have a wifi card on lenovo thinkserver ts140